# BOOLEAN allocate_items(struct item * items, size_t howmany) function for allocate an array of struct item

Tags: c, arrays, struct, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

Recently, I'm learning C. I found a question on the internet. The question is:

> What is the problem with this function in terms of memory allocation?
>   What is a good solution? You may assume that a struct item type has
>   been declared. The purpose of this function is to allocate an array of
>   struct item, which you may assume has been declared prior to this
>   function.
>
> ```
> BOOLEAN allocate_items(struct item * items, size_t howmany)
> { 
>    size_t count; 
>    items = malloc(sizeof(struct item) * howmany); 
>
>    if(!items) { 
>       perror("failed to allocate memory"); 
>       return FALSE; 
>    }
>    return TRUE;
>
> }
> ```

So, I think that the 4th line is wrong. It should be like:

```
items = malloc(sizeof(struct item));
```

And also the 6th line is wrong. It should be like:

```
if(items == NULL){
```

Is it correct?

Comment: Would you care to explain *why* you think those changes are necessary?

Comment: Not to mention the unused variable count... And that the items argument is wrong (should be ``struct item **items`` and that a homemade boolean is used (see ``stdbool.h``) and that you should compare to NULL (nullptr), with the nullptr being on the left and that your functions should have single point of exit and this one returns at more than one point...apart of all that, this is great code :)

Comment: best practice is to write the constant left. So you write ``if(NULL == *items)`` with item here already fixed...see comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, both line 4 and 6, as you mentioned seems to be OK.

That said, the basic problem with this function is, you're allocating memory to a *local* scope of variable. This way

- as you don't return the pointer to allocated memory, after the function returns, there would be no way to access the allocated memory.
- by not freeing up the allocated memory, you will face memory leak.

If you have to allocate memory *to* a pointer, you need to pass the address of that pointer to the function and allocate memory. You can also return the pointer but then you need to change the function signature.

Finally, [arrays are not pointers and vice-versa](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html). They may appear or beahave similar *sometimes*, but they are not the same.

Answer (score -1):

The 4th line is not wrong as they are trying to declare an array of the structs.
You should add a line inside the function that declares a new pointer, temp, to hold the current value of items, then after allocating the memory,
the 6th line should be

```
if(items == temp)
```

to check whether the value has changed(because that is the closest we can get to checking whether malloc worked)

this is because the ! operator is used to check if a condition is true or not(at least at a basic level in most languages) and as a pointer isn't a condition or an int that can be used as true or false, the operator won't work.

Comment: Wrong and wrong. Temporary variable or not, `items` is local; assigning to it won't be visible outside of the function. And checking for non-null with `if (!variable)` is just fine (although perhaps not the most readable).

Answer (score -1):

Here a fixed version, as it would probably be written in the "industry".

```
bool allocate_items(struct item ** pitems, size_t howmany)
{ 
   // argument validation 
   assert(NULL != pitems); // some also add release version checks...
   if(NULL == pitems ) return false;
   // We can also spot memory leak sources here.
   // If *pItems != NULL - does that mean we have to free first to prevent 
   // a leak? What if it is just some random value and not something we can 
   // free? So contract usually is: *pitems has to be NULL...
   assert(NULL == *pitems);
   if(NULL != *pitems) return false;

   // implementation
   *pitems = malloc(sizeof(struct item) * howmany); 

   if(NULL == *pitems) { 
       perror("failed to allocate memory"); 
   }
   return NULL != *pitems;
}
```

While the bool defined in `stdbool.h` sometimes causes trouble with C++ interop (same symbols on both sides, but sometimes `sizeof(bool)` differs), it is still the better option compared to inventing yet another bool type.

The `pitems` is a pointer to the location where the pointer to the new chunk of memory shall be written to. A caller of this function might have written:

```
int main(int argc, const char*[] argv) {
    struct item *myBunchOfStuff = NULL;
    if(false != allocate_items( &myBunchOfStuff, 20) ) {
        // ...
        free(myBunchOfStuff);
        myBunchOfStuff = NULL;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Defensive programming states: Your function cannot claim "Heh - my function only crashed because I was given a bad value!". Instead, it has to verify itself. It is responsible **not** to crash. The pointer could still be != NULL but otherwise bad. That is impossible for the function to catch, usually.

In C, everyone is proud of not requiring the cast of `malloc()`'s return value. You can be proud of that until you compile your code with a C++ compiler. Then you have to change your code and fix that. Well, I guess it is a matter of preference...

While parameter checking is often seen as a separate part of the functions implementation, after that, you should try to stick to "single point of exit". Main reason for that is maintainability. With multiple exit points, if the function gets bigger later on, it gets harder to spot if some early exit forgets to free some memory or cleanup other forms of state.